# How to construct GCP org policy with tag rules to apply to cloud run service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, gcp-iam

I am trying to default my Cloud Run services ingress access to be internal only unless a specific tag is being set on the service by the service owner (for instance).

I am trying to achieve this with org policies and tags.

Found the relevant org policy (Allowed ingress settings (Cloud Run)) and figured I create a "public" tag for those specific services.

I configured the policy to

- "allow all" if tag is public
- allow "internal" if tag is internal

I've set "internal" tag to the project - this resulted in desired state - only "internal traffic" setting was not grayed out on the service "trigger" configuration tab.
But when I applied "public" tag to the same service, other settings were still greyed out, as if the tag did not take affect or my policy conditions are wrong.

What am I missing?